# How to create aggregate function, like sum, with an implicit DISTINCT?

Tags: postgresql, aggregate, distinct

We have an ERP system which allows aggregates to be used (eg `SUM(foo)`) but not with DISTINCT (eg `SUM(DISTINCT foo)`.

Is it possible to create an aggregate function (`SUM_DISTINCT`), that returns the same result as as `SUM(DISTINCT foo)`, so `SUM_DISTINCT(foo) = SUM(DISTINCT foo)`?

Comment: What "ERP system" is that? Does it allow subqueries?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is it possible to create an aggregate function (`SUM_DISTINCT`), that returns the same result as as `SUM(DISTINCT foo)`, so `SUM_DISTINCT(foo) = SUM(DISTINCT foo)`?

Yes, it is possible — you need a [User-defined Aggregate](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/xaggr.html), such as this:

```
create or replace function f_sum_distinct (numeric[], numeric) returns numeric[]
    language sql as $$
select $1||$2;
$$;

create or replace function f_sum_distinct_final (numeric[]) returns numeric 
    language sql as $$
select sum(v) from (select distinct unnest($1) v) z;
$$;

create aggregate sum_distinct(numeric)
( sfunc     = f_sum_distinct
 ,stype     = numeric[]
 ,finalfunc = f_sum_distinct_final
);

with w(v) as (select 2 union all select 2 union all select 3)
select sum(v) "Plain SUM", sum(distinct v) "SUM(DISTINCT)", sum_distinct(v) "SUM_DISTINCT" from w;

/*
|Plain SUM|SUM(DISTINCT)|SUM_DISTINCT|
|--------:|------------:|-----------:|
|        7|            5|           5|
*/
```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=bfa0bd06979d0df47fbc0ccf4bb4dbc1)*

Note though (thanks @Erwin), that performance is going to be [very substantially worse](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=adfe82517e478f1d2f0e211690abbdb6) than the built-in aggregates. If this matters you will have to consider writing the helper functions in C, which is much more of an undertaking.

Comment: It should be mentioned that performance is *much* slower than `sum(DISTINCT foo)`. I ran a quick test on a table with 46k rows. As expected, `sum_distinct(foo)` was 1000x slower than `sum(DISTINCT foo)`. And it does not scale well, i.e. it gets worse with bigger tables. IOW: don't use it unless you positively have to.

Comment: Thanks @Erwin. In some cases you can use built-in functions for `sfunc` and `f_sum_distinct_final` which [can be](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=adfe7da8c2a5ca3c17a2453086dac4ca) substantially faster than roll-your-own functions (or you could writhe them in C of course). I tried to search for a built-in function called `numeric_accum` but although I found some references I couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand the problem. Just to rehash...

```
>>> 1+2+3+4+5
15
```

Now sample data.

```
CREATE TABLE foo
AS
  SELECT trunc(random()*5+1) AS x
  FROM generate_series(1,100);
```

Then we `SUM(DISTINCT..)`

```
SELECT SUM(DISTINCT x)
FROM foo;
 sum 
-----
  15
```

If as @JackDouglas suggests you want your own aggregate with distinct, just create the aggregate, [from the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/xaggr.html)

> Aggregate function calls in SQL allow `DISTINCT` and `ORDER BY` options that control which rows are fed to the aggregate's transition function and in what order. **These options are implemented behind the scenes and are not the concern of the aggregate's support functions.**

I just don't see what this has to do with `DISTINCT`

If you want to know how to impliment your own `sum()` it's almost in the docs exactly (over the `complex` type)

```
CREATE AGGREGATE mysum (numeric)
(
    sfunc = numeric_add,
    stype = numeric,
    initcond = '0'
);

SELECT mysum(x)
FROM ( VALUES (1),(5),(8),(8),(8) )
  AS t(x);

SELECT mysum(DISTINCT x)
FROM ( VALUES (1),(5),(8),(8),(8) )
  AS t(x);
```

As a special note `numeric_add(numeric,numeric)` is an [undocumented internal function](https://doxygen.postgresql.org/backend_2utils_2adt_2numeric_8c_source.html#l02248). It's used by the `+` operator, but you can put anything you want there that takes two `numeric`.